# cannot connect to minikube ip and NodePort service port - windows

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to run an application locally on k8s but I am not able to reach it.

here is my deloyment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: listings
  labels:
    app: listings
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: listings
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: listings
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mydockerhub/listings:latest
          name: listings
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: listings-secret
            - configMapRef:
                name: listings-config
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: django-port
```

and it is my service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: listings
  labels:
    app: listings
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: listings
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 30036
      protocol: TCP
```

At this stage, I don't want to use other methods like ingress or ClusterIP, or load balancer. I want to make nodePort work because I am trying to learn.

When I run `kubectl get svc -o wide` I see

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
listings     NodePort    10.107.77.231   <none>        8000:30036/TCP   28s   app=listings
```

When I run `kubectl get node -o wide` I see

```
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION                      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   85d   v1.23.3   192.168.49.2   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS   5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2   docker://20.10.12
```

and when I run `minikube ip` it shows `192.168.49.2`

I try to open `http://192.168.49.2:30036/health` it is not opening `This site can’t be reached`

How should expose my application externally?

note that I have created the required configmap and secret objects. also note that this is a simple django restful application that if you hit the /health endpoint, it returns success. and that's it. so there is no problem with the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your local and minikube are not in the same network segment,
you must do something more to access minikube service on windows.

First

```
$ minikube service list
```

That will show your service detail which include name, url, nodePort, targetPort.

Then

```
$ minikube service --url listings
```

It will open a port to listen on your windows machine that can forward the traffic to minikube node port.

Or you can use command `kubectl port-forward` to expose service on host port, like:

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 -n default service/listings 30036:8000
```

Then try with `http://localhost:30036/health`

Comment: `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 -n default service/listings 30036:8000` worked! When I ran the command, the windows firewall asked me for permission to allow private and public networks which I allowed private.
but the first approach did not.